# XAMARIN iOS iPad Pro Fullscreen Issue

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

have somebody also the problem with the new iOS 13.4.1 and the fullscreen mode?
My App should look like this:
[image]

But it looks like this if I am using new iOS:
[image]

I am using Xamarin with C#.

Comment: Is it the same on the bottom, or is it cut just from the top?

Comment: are you using `ios:useSafeAreaInsets="true"` ?

Comment: @MihailDuchev it is only on the top. I think I am don't using `ios:useSafeAreaInsets="true"` but I try this out.

Comment: It seems that you tested the app on iPad Pro . Which has a different  aspect ratios with iPad Air and Mini . So you could share the code or sample so that I can test it on my side .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT you are right. If I am testing it on an iPad Air (3rd generation) I don't see this issue. So it seems to be not a problem with the iOS and a problem with the aspect ratio on the iPad Pro. Thank you for the offer for the sample code, but I don't know what I can share since this old project is owned by my customer.